# How to load files from a Tomcat's mapped folder in java code?

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7

I have mapped a server directory in my Tomcat 7 and placed the file in /conf/Catalina/localhost/mywebapp#documents.xml

The xml file's content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="/Users/myuser/temp/mywebappfiles/documents" />
```

Now I'm trying to load the files under that mapped folder from my java code but without success. I have tried this:

```
servletContext.getRealPath("/mywebappfiles/documents/document1.pdf");
```

But no success.

So I would like to know if I'm going into the right direction with the folder mapping and also I would like to know what is the best way to load those files in my java code?

Thank you,

Gyo

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify a context:

```
<Context path="/doc" docBase="/Users/myuser/temp/mywebappfiles/documents" />
```

Then you will be able to access the file `document1.pdf` with this url `http://localhost:8080/doc/document1.pdf`.

One way to load a file in Java is to use an URI (using the server path):

```
File document1 = new File("/Users/myuser/temp/mywebappfiles/documents/document1.pdf");
```

Comment: Hi, The way I did I'm able to load say an image from that mapped folder in a CSS file, e.g. background-image: url('/doc/documents/logo.png') However in java code it's not working when I try to load a File with the absolute path. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to get the file using the URL you can use an URL Object then read the content using a FileOutputStream. Here a tutorial http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=207&t=How_To_Read_A_PDF_File_From_A_URL_In_Java